# What is the argument for Kuni being a worthy leader, when all others fail?

Tags: ken-liu, the-dandelion-dynasty

*The Grace of Kings* is deeply concerned with the mechanics of power - who has it; how to get it; how to keep it; what price you pay for it.

Through its course, the book surveys a great many rulers and would-be rulers. In each case, the book portrays power as a corrupting force, that turns rulers to paths of indulgence and self-preservation -- which sooner or later devastate the society being ruled, destroying the ruler as well. The book also points out that those most drawn to power are often the ones who will wield it least wisely.

To all this, Kuni is an exception. His wisdom in ruling seems smooth and unquestioned. This is apparent at every point - from the complete lack of repercussions for the looting of Pan, under his command (compare to the harsh judgement of Mata's character we're supposed to accept, when he is forced to make human sacrifice to Tazu); all the way to the utopian portrayal of the kingdoms united under his rule:

> The beggar's face fell at this news. "Then it is even more generous of you to share food with a stranger. You're certain your parents will not mind?"
>
> The boy laughed. "There's no need to worry. King Kuni and Prime Minister Yelu ordered grain to be shipped from Gefica, and all of us have plenty to eat.
>
> "You like the king then? Even though he is not from Xana?"
>
> "We no longer speak of Xana," said the boy.
>
> "But that's your country!"
>
> The boy shook his head. "This is Rui, an Island of Dara."

**What is it that makes Kuni so exceptional?** Why is he worthy and successful, when all the others are not? What is it that makes him able to navigate the minefield of rebellion, leadership, and power, without succumbing to all the same traps that every other leader in the book does?